# Can you attack again after I decide not to block?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

We are both new to MTG. He will attack me, and when I decide to take the hit and roll back my life, he then likes to attack me a second time. This doesn't feel right to me, is this allowed? Can he hit me twice after I've blocked or taken the hits?

Comment: There are some card games that have a mechanic like this, but even in all of those I know about, if you wanted to block the subsequent attacks, you could then choose to do so.  Your opponent may have learned this in one of those, but as the answers point out, he will need to unlearn this for Magic.

Comment: Keep in mind that Lightning Bolt and such are not attacks. He may cast as many of spells and activate as many abilities as he can.

Comment: Also, you might be "damaged twice" even if you aren't attacked twice. **[CR 510.5]**. If at least one attacking or blocking creature has first strike (see rule 702.7) or double strike (see rule 702.4) **as the combat damage step begins**, the only creatures that assign combat damage in that step are those with first strike or **double strike**. After that step, instead of proceeding to the end of combat step, the phase gets a **second combat damage step**. [...]

Comment: I believe the OP's opponent's mistake was thinking of the ability to cast non-fast effects during the main phase *before* and *after* combat. A second opportunity to cast spells, not attack.

Answer (score 11):

**No, you can only attack once per turn**

There are certain cards that give you a second attack, but normally, one attack per turn.

If you are new to Magic, you should have a look at the [Basic Rulebook (pdf)](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/resources/rules/EN_MTGM14_PrintedRulebook_LR.pdf) on the Magic [rules website](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules). It contains all the essential info to get you started.

If you encounter situations not quite covered there, you can always check back here, or try to figure it out yourself in the Comprehensive Rulebook (don't use that one to start out).

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not correct. You usually only have one combat phase (There are exceptions using cards that give additional combat phases.)

Imagine this is not the case and you don't have any blockers. Then you could be dead on turn 2 by a 1/1 creature attacking as many times as you like.

Answer (score 2):

As most have pointed out, there is only 1 attack phase.

The exception would be if a card explicitly states a second combat phase, e.g. [Aurelia, the Warleader](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Aurelia%2C%20the%20Warleader):

> Whenever Aurelia, the Warleader attacks for the first time each turn, untap all creatures you control. After this phase, there is an additional combat phase.